# How to create kernel panic when deadlock happens due to mutex lock?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, mutex, deadlock, panic

I want to manually create a kernel panic using mutex based deadlock. 
I created 2 kernel threads in a module & did recursive mutex lock. So one of the thread again acquire the lock & put into deadlock situation. I understand that using mutex, system went to sleep state, so device is not getting crashed. Is there any mechanism, that I can create a panic when deadlock happens due to mutex lock?

```
int foo1(void *data)
{
    while(!kthread_should_stop()) {
        mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
        global_variable++;
        mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
        msleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}

int foo2(void *data)
{
    while(!kthread_should_stop()) {
        mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
        global_variable++;
        mutex_lock(&my_mutex);  // Recursive lock
        mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
        msleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}

static int __init driver_init(void)
{
        if((alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, 0, 1, "my_Dev")) <0){
                printk(KERN_INFO "Cannot allocate major number\n");
                return -1;
        }
        cdev_init(&my_cdev,&fops);

        if((cdev_add(&my_cdev,dev,1)) < 0){
            printk(KERN_INFO "Cannot add the device to the system\n");
        }

        if((device_create(dev_class,NULL,dev,NULL,"my_device")) == NULL){
            printk(KERN_INFO "Cannot create the Device\n");
            class_destroy(dev_class);
        }

        mutex_init(&my_mutex);

        my_thread1 = kthread_run(foo1,NULL,"my Thread1");
        if(my_thread1) {
            printk(KERN_ERR "Kthread1 Created Successfully...\n");
        } else {
            printk(KERN_ERR "Cannot create kthread1\n");
        }

        my_thread2 = kthread_run(foo2,NULL,"my Thread2");
        if(my_thread2) {
            printk(KERN_ERR "Kthread2 Created Successfully...\n");
        } else {
            printk(KERN_ERR "Cannot create kthread2\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Using above code, I'm able to create the deadlock. But I'm looking for a kernel panic, so that I can do the debugging for this error.

Comment: How about running `sysctl kernel.softlockup_panic=1`?

Comment: You can also call panic() from within your code.

Comment: @PeterL. If I call panic() from the code, then I'll get dumps because of that. But I want the dumps due to watchdog bite from deadlock using mutex.

Comment: @IanAbbott I already used this. Please find it below.
/etc # sysctl -a | grep kernel.softlockup_panic                                                                                                                                                   
kernel.softlockup_panic = 1
Still, my device is not getting crashed.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, the only effect of the mutex deadlock in `foo2` is to put the kernel thread to sleep. There is nothing to prevent other tasks being scheduled on the CPU that was running that kernel thread, so no soft lockup condition will occur. You should be able to detect the deadlock using the lock debugging kernel config options, but I don't think there is an option to call panic() when a locking violation occurs.

Comment: You need to trigger the watchdog timer in the kernel.  I believe that will trigger if timer interrupts are disabled for 10 seconds.

Comment: @stark - I'm sorry. But how to trigger the watchdog timer in kernel? Do you mean to run echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger?

Comment: You want the watchdog to trigger. I explained in my comment what triggers the watchdog.  It has nothing to do with sysrq.  It has nothing to do with deadlocks.  It has to do with timer interrupts, that's it.